# In Excel, populate same data in a column. The number of rows populated must be equal to rows in adjacent column

Tags: excel, macros

I have data say upto 10 rows in columnA, and in some columns say for example columnE and columnG I have data starting in 2nd row, as first rows are headers. Now, I need to populate data in columnE and columnG till the row equivalent to ColumnA. The data is same as in 2ND cell of each columnE and G.

Please help me as I am not a programmer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I want to fill specific columns with same data in their 2nd cell upto rows equivalent to maximum rows in some other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for column **G**:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G3:G" & N).Value = Range("G2").Value
End Sub
```